# Getting ToString method of an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, webapi

I am trying to get the ToString method of an enum like this

```
  var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Program), "x");
  var toStringMethod = typeof(Enum).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[0]);
  Expression leftExpression = Expression.Call(property, toStringMethod);
```

but this is returning null when passing it.

Comment: You've got a variable of type `Program` (which is presumably a class), and you're trying to call the `Enum.ToString()` method on it. What are you actually trying to do here? Are you trying to work with an enum, or a `Program`, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying that you want a method on `Enum` called `ToString` which has a single parameter of type `Enum`.

But that's not the signature of `Enum.ToString`. `Enum.ToString` has the [following overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=net-6.0):

```
string ToString();
string ToString (string? format);
// and two obsolete overloads
```

Look for the correct parameter types, and you're fine:

```
var toStringMethod = typeof(Enum).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[0]);
```

or:

```
var toStringMethod = typeof(Enum).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });
```

Comment: I have updated my question, but when i try that it throws the error    System.ArgumentException: 'Method 'System.String ToString()' declared on type 'System.Enum' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Int32''                                                            It Does that on the last line

Comment: Note, it's rude to change your question after someone has succesfully answered it. If I answered your question, please accept the answer. If you accidentally asked the wrong question, feel free to ask another.